# When using a systemd <service>.socket, which file descriptor receives the socket(s)?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, systemd

When I create a `<service>.socket` systemd file, I can include entries such as:

```
ListenDatagram=/run/<service>/listen.sock
ListenFIFO=/run/<service>/IPC.FIFO
```

etc.

The [systemd.socket documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) says that those sockets are passed to my application as file descriptor. What I do not see is: which file descriptors are these? Will that be 3, 4, 5... etc.? Or does it replace 0 (input) and 1 (output)?

In other words, in my software, how do I know what's what?

---

Note that I assume my `<service>.socket` will use:

```
Accept=no
```

Because `Accept=yes` clearly says it works like `inetd`, which means `stdin` and `stdout` receive the in and out sockets as expected (for a TCP stream, that would be the same socket duplicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be 3, 4, 5, 6 ...

> sd_listen_fds() may be invoked by a daemon to check for file
> descriptors passed by the service manager as part of the socket-based
> activation logic. It returns the number of received file descriptors.
> If no file descriptors have been received, zero is returned. The first
> file descriptor may be found at file descriptor number 3 (i.e.
> SD_LISTEN_FDS_START), the remaining descriptors follow at 4, 5, 6, …,
> if any.

Comment: Oh! It uses environment variables. Cool. This looks like a neat feature too. You can start/stop your service and still receive connections without a huge memory footprint. It will be useful for _background_ services used just once a day or so.